# Spermatogenesis question

Tags: human-biology, reproduction, human-physiology, sexual-reproduction

I found this diagram in my textbook regarding the process of spermatogenesis. But, I doubt if the labelling done is correct or not. Especially, I can't figure out any difference between the cells labelled as spermatids and those as spermatozoa. Also, I doubt the labelling of Sertoli cells.
Please help me clarify my doubt.
[image: Diagrammatic sectional view of a seminiferous tubule]

As per my textbook,

> The spermatids are transformed into **spermatozoa (sperms)** by the process called **spermiogenesis**. After spermiogenesis, sperm heads become embedded in the **Sertoli cells**, and are finally released from the seminiferous tubules by the process called **spermiation**.

Comment: I edited your question to convert the image of text to actual searchable text.

Answer (score 3):

Notice the cell labeled "spermatid" is still attached to the Sertoli cell. Once released from the Sertoli cell, spermatids are called spermatozoa.

This process (release of the spermatid to form a spermatazoon) is called [spermiation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3158646/)

#### EDIT

The text you added is still correct, but not well explained. Spermiogenesis is the development of the spermatid, the haploid 1N gamete produced by the second meiotic division, into a cell with a long flagella with a small amount of cytoplasm. Spermiation is the release from the sertoli cell. Both spermiogenesis and spermiation are involved in the development of a spermatid to a spermatozoon, but the specific point where we stop calling them spermatids and start calling them spermatozoa is release by the Sertoli cell, or spermiation, a substantial process in its own right. Both spermiogenesis and spermiation are important steps in the conversion of the haploid 1N gamete to a motile, free spermatozoon.

Comment: Your answer does not match at all to the theory in my book. Please see my edited question again and help me out. Thanks.

Comment: @DJKoustav your text is still correct, but not well explained.

Comment: @DJKoustav If my answer doesn't fully answer your question now, let me know. Otherwise, please mark it the answer by checking the gray checkmark next to it. See [someone answers](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks!